# getSelection... опять. Как определить в каком елементе находиться выделенное слово?

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

```
function getSelectionText() {
    var text = "";
    var activeEl = document.activeElement;
    var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
    if (
      (activeElTagName == "textarea") || (activeElTagName == "input" &&
      /^(?:text|search|password|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type)) &&
      (typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
    ) {
        text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
    } else if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    }
    return text;
}
```

***например*** есть:

```
<p>Миссия  — повышать качество жизни людей , приобщая их к мировой эногастрономической культуре.</p>
<p>Шаг за шагом реализовать эту миссию нам помогает интегрированный подход к ведению бизнеса: собственная школа сомелье, книжное издательство, эногастрономическое туристическое агентство и другие проекты. </p>
```

посредством функции getSelection выбираем слово "качество". Как получить ссылку именно на тот абзац, в котором находиться это слово?

Answer (score 0):

Элемент, в котором находится начало выделенного текста -

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode
```

конец выделенного текста -

```
window.getSelection().focusNode
```

скорее всего это будет textNode, так что вам нужен

```
window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentElement
```

[Документация объекта Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Selection)

```js
document.addEventListener("selectionchange", event => {
  const startNode = window.getSelection().anchorNode;
  const endNode = window.getSelection().focusNode;
  console.log(
      startNode.nodeName,
      startNode.parentElement,
      endNode.nodeName,
      endNode.parentElement
  );
})
```

```html
<b>Миссия  — повышать качество жизни людей , приобщая их к мировой эногастрономической культуре.</b>
<p>Шаг за шагом реализовать эту миссию нам помогает интегрированный подход к ведению бизнеса: собственная школа сомелье, книжное издательство, эногастрономическое туристическое агентство и другие проекты. </p>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!) Вроде, разобрался!)